# Manipulating backreferences for substitution in perl

Tags: regex, perl

As a part of an attempt to replace scientific numbers with decimal numbers I want to save a backreference into a string variable, but it doesn't work.

My input file is:

```
,8E-6,
,-11.78E-16,
,-17e+7,
```

I then run the following:

```
open FILE, "+<C:/Perl/input.txt" or die $!;
open(OUTPUT, "+>C:/Perl/output.txt") or die;

while (my $lines = <FILE>){

  $find = "(?:,)(-?)(0|[1-9][0-9]*)(\.)?([0-9]*)?([eE])([+\-]?)([0-9]+)(?:,)";
  $noofzeroesbeforecomma = eval("$7-length($4)");
  $replace = '"foo $noofzeroesbeforecomma bar"';

  $lines =~ s/$find/$replace/eeg;
  print (OUTPUT $lines);
}

close(FILE);
```

I get

```
foo  bar
foo  bar
foo  bar
```

where I would have expected

```
foo 6 bar
foo 14 bar
foo 7 bar
```

`$noofzeroesbeforecomma` seems to be empty or non-existant.

Even with the following adjustment I get an empty result

```
$noofzeroesbeforecomma = $2;
```

Only inserting `$2` directly in the replace string gives me something (which is then, unfortunately, not what I want).

Can anyone help?

I'm running Strawberry Perl (5.16.1.1-64bit) on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine, and quite inexperienced with Perl

Comment: You use `$4` and `$7` before you ever use the match or substitution operator to set them.

Comment: Sorry, am I misunderstanding this? Your second input line is `-11.78E-16`. If you're trying to capture the exponent _sans sign_don't you expect to see `16` and not `14` as in `foo 14 bar` , in your desired output near the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is not using

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

`warnings` would have told you

```
Use of uninitialized value $7 in concatenation (.) or string at ...
Use of uninitialized value $4 in concatenation (.) or string at ...
```

I would recommend you try and find a module that can handle scientific notation, rather than trying to hack your own.

Your code, in a working order might look something like this. As you can see, I have put a `q()` around your eval string to avoid it being evaluated before `$7` and `$4` exists. I also removed the eval itself, since while double eval on an eval is somewhat excessive.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $lines = <DATA>) {
    my $find="(?:,)(-?)(0|[1-9][0-9]*)(\.)?([0-9]*)?([eE])([+\-]?)([0-9]+)(?:,)";
    my $noof = q|$7-length($4)|;
    $lines =~ s/$find/$noof/eeg;
    print $lines;
}


__DATA__
,8E-6,
,-11.78E-16,
,-17e+7,
```

**Output:**

```
6
14
7
```

As a side note, not using `strict` is asking for trouble. Doing it while using a variable name such as `$noofzeroesbeforecomma` is asking for twice the trouble, as it is rather easy to make typos.

Comment: I think simply "not using strict is asking for trouble" says it all

Comment: @Borodin Double trouble, as it were.

Comment: I would also suggest learning about the `x` flag on regular expression operators. This makes it possible to use linebreaks and comments in your regular expression, which is a great help with complicated regexes.

Answer (score 0):

This is not about backreferences but the original problem, transforming numbers from scientific notation. I'm sure there are some cases in which this fails:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use bignum;

for (<DATA>) {
    next unless /([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)[Ee]([+-]\d+)/;
    print $1 * 10 ** $2 . "\n";
}

__DATA__
,8E-6,
,-11.78E-16,
,-17e+7,
```

Output:

```
0.000008
-0.000000000000001178
-170000000
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the [`Regexp::Common::number`](https://metacpan.org/module/Regexp%3a%3aCommon%3a%3anumber) plugin for the [`Regexp::Common`](https://metacpan.org/module/Regexp%3a%3aCommon) module which will find all real numbers for you and allow you to replace those that have an exponent marker

This code shows the idea. using the `-keep` option makes the module put each component into one of the `$N` variables. The exponent marker - `e` or `E` - is in `$7`, so the number can be transformed depending on whether this was present

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Regexp::Common;

my $real_re = $RE{num}{real}{-keep};

while (<>) {
  s/$real_re/ $7 ? sprintf '%.20f', $1 : $1 /eg;
  print;
}
```

**output**

Given your example input, this code produces the following. The values can be tidied up further using additional code in the substitution

```
,0.00000800000000000000,
,-0.00000000000000117800,
,-170000000.00000000000000000000,
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Perl can handle *all* those types of expressions. And since the standard item of data in Perl is the string, you would only need to *capture* the expression to use it. So, take this expression:

```
/(-?\d+(?:.\d+)?[Ee][+-]?\d+)/
```

to extract it from the surrounding text and use `sprintf` to format it, like Borodin showed.

*However*, if it helps you to see a better case of what you tried to do, this works better

```
my ( $whole, $frac, $expon )
    = $line =~ m/(?:,)-?(0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.(\d*))?[eE]([+\-]?\d+)(?:,)/
    ;
my $num = $expon - length( $frac );
```

- Why not capture the sign with the exponent *anyway*, if you're going to do arithmetic with it?
- It's better to name your captures and eschew `eval` when it's not necessary.
- The substitution--as is--doesn't make much sense.
- Really, since neither the symbols or the digits can be case sensitive, just put a `(?i)` at the beginning, and avoid the E "character class" `[Ee]`:

  ```
  /((?i)-?\d+(?:.\d+)?e[+-]?\d+)/
  ```